# Drawing an image in html5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, haxe

i currently want to implement a draw image tool to my projects(something like the brush tool but instead of a color i am actually drawing with the picture). I want to be able to "draw" a picture by hovering my mouse over it. I m currently thinking about two possibilities, one is with a mask over the picture and actually erasing the mask with the mouse or the other posibility to try to draw with the canvas, making the zones touched by the mouse visible. 
Do you have some general ideas about how should i start my work?
Thanks

Comment: This might help http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the canvas approach.

Here is another great tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-based-drawing-application-using-canvas--net-14288